# Hot/Cold Water Faucet Dripping

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet, sink, kitchen-sink

I have a water heating system in my kitchen sink (picture below) that is about 4 years old.  All of a sudden the faucet is dripping water.  I am trying to figure out how to fix it. I tried cleaning the levers but that did not help since I was unable to reach deep inside.  How can I disassemble the levers so I can clean it very well and see if the dropping stops.  Any pointers or videos would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: WD-40 (or any petroleum-based product) is probably bad for the (probably) rubber seals in the valve.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a mounting nut on the faucet stem which holds the faucet from below (under the counter). You will need to shut off water heater AND the water to the heater, and disconnect the supply pipes. Take the mounting nut off and pull the faucet out. When you look inside you will find something similar to the armature for pop-up drain plugs (I think). Basically you should be able to see how everything goes in and how to take it apart once the faucet is has been taken off the counter. There should be a rubber ring that can be replaced. If you can't figure it out once the faucet is off, take a picture of the inner workings and post it so that someone here will be able to help.

Comment: Will try that. It is a bit hard to get to it since I have a water filter and tank in the same space